# Swift Find Scene By Name

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

How do i make a Swift sprite kit game jump to another scene by searching for the scene with a string. so:

```
let scenename : String = "Map1"

let scene : SKSCene = SkScene.getscene(scenename)
```

Do we have something like that?

if not please help me with alternatives!

Thanks for your help and time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a delegate call to your SKView from current scene, which is presenting the scene then present another scene like this:

```
let newScene = SKScene.init(fileNamed: "MyScene")
newScene!.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.Fil
let reaveal = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(0.01)
let aSKView = self.view as! SKView
aSKView.presentScene(newScene!, transition: reaveal)
```

Do check for memory leaks ;)

Comment: Can you add your code here? Are you having the scene file added to your target? Or you are creating it programmatically.

Comment: let newScene = SkScene.init(fileNamed: "Map_1_1")
newScene.scaleMode = scaleMode
let reaveal = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(0.01)
self.view?.presentScene(newScene, transition: reaveal)

Comment: let newScene = SKScene.init(fileNamed: "Map_1_1")
        newScene!.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.Fill
        let reaveal = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(0.01)
        let aSKView = self.view as! SKView
        aSKView.presentScene(newScene!, transition: reaveal)      
This should work perfectly, if you have added the file to your bundle with correct name

Comment: it still gave me an error but thanks for your time and help i will try to find some alternatives!